# Explain me: webpack, gulp and react, redux

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, gulp, electron

Please, let some nice and patient person explain me what tool do I need and why?

I use React and I will use Redux and also Rlectron and semantic-ui library which needs gulp.

So my question is: Do I need webpack?
What is the main difference and how to deal with it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's primary opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need `gulp` for what you described. webpack will serve you well. Also, [react-semantic-ui](https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction) has a react binding so you don't need extra build steps for that.

Why webpack? It's a much safer choice at this moment for bundling and building a react app.

- Most of the tutorials you find are based on webpack.
- It has many plugins to deal with every scenario.
- Can easily run your ESLint through webpack so you'll get nice errors and warnings at your build time.
- Well integrated with React and its ecosystem.